# Required permissions are not granted. At least one of these permissions must be granted: Managing organization tree

Tags: c#, aspnetboilerplate, aspnetzero

I am using ASP.NET Zero MVC/jQuery edition for .NET Core.

I am attempting to create an Organization Unit (OU) for a tenant from a controller on the host side and running into an issue.

The following line of code:

```
await _organizationUnitAppService.CreateOrganizationUnit(organizationUnitDto);
```

Generates the following error:

> Required permissions are not granted. At least one of these permissions must be granted: Managing organization tree

The full code I am using:

```
CreateOrganizationUnitInput organizationUnitDto = new CreateOrganizationUnitInput()
{
    DisplayName = OUCode
};

var user = _userManager.FindByNameAsync(TenantName);
using (_session.Use(TenantID, user.Id))
{
    try
    {
        await _organizationUnitAppService.CreateOrganizationUnit(organizationUnitDto);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        var e = ex.Message.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`_organizationUnitAppService.CreateOrganizationUnit` has the `AbpAuthorize` attribute:

```cs
[AbpAuthorize(AppPermissions.Pages_Administration_OrganizationUnits_ManageOrganizationTree)]
public async Task<OrganizationUnitDto> CreateOrganizationUnit(CreateOrganizationUnitInput input)
```

Grant the `Managing organization tree` permission to the user:

```cs
var user = _userManager.FindByNameAsync(TenantName);
var permission = _permissionManager.GetPermission(AppPermissions.Pages_Administration_OrganizationUnits_ManageOrganizationTree) // Add this
await _userManager.GrantPermissionAsync(user, permission); // Add this

using (_session.Use(TenantID, user.Id))
{
    try
    {
        await _organizationUnitAppService.CreateOrganizationUnit(organizationUnitDto);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        var e = ex.Message.ToString();
    }
}
```